# Using CDROMREADMODE1 ioctl on CD-ROM results in EIO error?

Tags: linux, ioctl, cd-rom

I am developing an application which supports a relatively low-level CD interface, and am trying to read data sectors from the CD.

Reading the TOC works just fine, and querying CD type reveals it is a Mode 1 data CD (for what it's worth, it has a filesystem which is mounted as `/media/[username]/[cd label]` that I can browse in Thunar, so it doesn't appear to be corrupt)

Track 1 is listed as starting at MSF 0:2:0 (with the lead-out track starting at 8:47:49), so I try and issue a CDROMREADMODE1 as follows:

```
union {
    struct cdrom_msf msf;
    unsigned char buffer[CD_FRAMESIZE]; // 2048 bytes
} arg;
arg.msf.cdmsf_min0 = 0;
arg.msf.cdmsf_sec0 = 2;
arg.msf.cdmsf_frame0 = 0;

int result = ioctl(cd_handle, CDROMREADMODE1, &arg);
```

The resource I was reading indicated that only the start values in the cdrom_msf structure mattered, so I left the others unfilled.

However, the return value of this is always -1, with `errno` set to EIO, and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

I have tried googling for this, but unfortunately information on this seems to be relatively scarce so I'm kind of flying blind here. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: oh, interestingly a CDROMREADRAW ioctl succeeds. Is it possible this USB CD-ROM drive just does not support CDROMREADMODE1?

Comment: Now you are getting into manufacturer drive capabilities. I don't know the specific answer to your question, but the rule of thumb is that drives and disks have been removing features at a fairly rapid pace as they "consumerized" their products. It would be worthwhile to find (if possible) the technical documentation (datasheet) for the drive you are attempting to use. You may well find the feature you are trying to use isn't supported on the drive and everything (for example) is read as `CDROMREADRAW`. Especially true with a USB interface to the drive.

Comment: Also look at your `dmesg` startup file or the `log` file (or `journal` if using systemd) to look at how the device is being initialized either on boot or when you plug it in. That may shed additional light on the problem. Another avenue is to look at utilities that will show the device capabilities. Like `lsusb` or `lsblk` or the like to tease more information from the system. Even exploring `/dev/` or `/proc/` or `/sys/` for device and interface details. Sorry I don't have more than ideas of where I would start to offer.

Comment: One thing I found poking around is that despite apparently being a "mode 1" data CD, according to the track header the track is actually mode 2, form 1.
As a workaround, for now I just whipped up my own logic to issue a raw read, check the header (& subheader if mode 2), extract the 2048-byte data, and then does a quick CRC check against the EDC field (haven't bothered with error correction yet). So far seems to be working.

Comment: That's pretty much all you can do absent a specific datasheet for that drive. If you can make the raw read work, then that is the way to go. Much of the old documentation was written based on hardware manufactured 25 years ago and hasn't been updated as features waned. Good job on your persistence and finding a path forward.